# Replace MacBook Pro screen with Screen from old MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a 13” MacBook Pro mid 2014 as well as a late 2011 MacBook Pro.

My 2014 MacBook Pro screen is broken and I was wondering if I could replace it with the screen from my 2011 MacBook Pro.

Will there be any issues during installation?

Answer (score 5):

**No, it will not work.**

First, and most importantly, the LVDS connectors are not interchangeable.  The 2011 MacBook Pro uses the 30 pin LVDS connector while the 2014 uses the 40pin connector (left and right respectively).

[image]
[image]

<sup>Images sourced from iFixit.com</sup>

Secondly, the display assembly also contains the cables for the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth antennas as well as the iSight (webcam) cable.  All of which are in very different locations on each of their respective logic boards, thus very different cable lengths; they physically won't fit.