# Is it possible to connect a 15" MacBook Pro screen to a 13" MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

I’m trying to fit late 2008 model 15 inch MacBook Pro screen to a 13 inch MacBook Air from 2013. Is this possible? Do you have experience with the display's sockets and connectors ?

This is a hobby project; I don’t mind if it costs more than a new MacBook Pro. I just wanna see a 15 inch MacBook Air! I have few other MacBook Pro 15 inch machines to kill.

The target resolution is 1400x900. I read that Retina display won’t work here as graphic card may not be giving the high resolution.

I am looking for guides, resources, or insights into how to achieve this.

Comment: Please could you let us know what you have tried and what specific step is causing problems? Have you disconnected the displays? Are cables and connections exposed? Do you have experience of this type of task from other projects? At the moment the question feels too broad to give specific answers.

Comment: My specific question is that I need connector for mba2013 board to mbp2008-15 screen. The mbp2008-15inch screen has an embedded driver, and so I’m asking what converter I can use for it? your Other question; yes I have some long experience in repair and have repair atelier with access to many tools.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It is not possible.  Similar to this question previously asked

- [Replace MacBook Pro screen with Screen from old MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351339/replace-macbook-pro-screen-with-screen-from-old-macbook/351347#351347)

The 2008 MacBook Pro uses a 30pin LVDS connector while the newer one uses the 40pin connector.